# ng-repeat always rendering as last in directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive (`<my-directive>`) and child directives (`<my-child-directive>`) as below structure:

```
<my-directive>
        <my-child-directive caption="{{student}}" ng-repeat="student in students"></my-child-directive>
        <my-child-directive caption="static content1"></my-child-directive>  
</my-directive>
```

The first child directive repeated using ng-repeat and The last child directive is a static item.

Now I have two questions here:

**Question1**:
In the final output, the last directive is rendering as first `<li>`. is there any way to render the `<li>s` in the same order of child directives?

**Question2:**
I have used a hidden div in `<my-directive>`'s template to render the *transclude* for temporary purpose. Is there any way to avoid this unwanted div?

here is my java script code:

```
app=angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller("MyController",function($scope){
    $scope.students=["Alex","George","Phillip"];
});


app.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        transclude:true,
        template:"<ul><li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item.caption}}</li></ul> <div ng-transclude ng-hide='true'></div>",
        controller:function($scope){
            $scope.items=[];
            this.addItem=function(subScope){ 
                 $scope.items.push(subScope);   
            }
        },
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){ 
        }
    };
});

app.directive('myChildDirective',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require:"^myDirective",
        scope:{
            caption:"@"
        },

        link:function(scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){
            parentCtrl.addItem(scope);
        }

    }
})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fyds082s/5/

Can anybody help on this?

Comment: It feels like you're taking the long road to solving a simpler issue - can you explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The link function of the second  directive is executed before the directives that come before him. When you check the ng-repeat state while the static directive is executed it shows that the index is 0. it hasn't finished compiling the ng-repeat yet.

My guess is that angular links sibling element from last to first, the same way it links from child elements first

**Update:**

My guess is wrong. so my new guess it has something to do with child scopes. For example, when adding ng-if to the second directive it is indeed executed second: http://jsfiddle.net/fyds082s/7/

```
<my-directive>
        <my-child-directive caption="{{student}}" ng-repeat="student in students"></my-child-directive>
        <my-child-directive caption="static content1" ng-if="true"></my-child-directive>  
</my-directive>
```

Comment: But please look http://jsfiddle.net/fyds082s/6/ . Here I removed parent directive and put one more static contents as last item. The last static element caption appearing in the second alert. The second alert should be the "static item 1"  if links sibling element from last to first. It showing  "static item 2" as second alert

Comment: That is great. However my directive is going to re use in different areas. Hence ng-if cant be always true . I need to remove child directives dynamically in some conditions. So is it possible to set priority dynamically without using ng-if ?

Comment: I'd suggest not relying on the order in which link functions are executed. Find a mechanism of sorting your array the way you want, and then you don't have to deal with that

Answer (score 0):

What order do you think the following would produce?

```
<my-directive>
  <my-child-directive caption="one" ng-if="true"></my-child-directive>
  <my-child-directive caption="two"></my-child-directive>
</my-directive>
```

If you answered `two, one` then hat's off to you.

The reason behind this somewhat unintuitive result is a "conditional rendering" directive like `ng-if` and `ng-repeat`. They both transclude their hosting element, but render it later - when [`$scope.$watch`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngIf.js#L89) or [`$scope.$watchCollection`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.15/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js#L384) fire an event, respectively - at which time the `link` function of `myChildDirective` is called.

The best approach is not to rely on the order of called `link` functions to determine the order of rendering.